# Strange Json Behavior with the same Request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic

I am using WebApi to sending the json data and i have Json structure that Contains:

```
{"totalAmount":0.01,"transactions":[{"Tokens":1,"transactionDI":1,"deviceUserDI":2,"routeDI":1,"DateTimeProceed":"\/Date(1406482920000+0100)\/","Typetran":1,"usedtokens":[{"usedtokenValue":9.32,"usedtokenType":3,"usedtokenId":"d798ee2d920e488487014d2a5ce46e7f"}]}],"numberofTransactions":1,"type":"insertit","validation":"68W956!8$97123@Y$"}
```

Which i am sending using fiddler and that is being accessed with `dynamic objectData` then Deserializing using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

After that i am inserting the same Request with `objectData.ToString()` into the Database, 
the same result is stored into the database (string result).

But When i am trying with

```
{
  "totalAmount": 0.01,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "Tokens": 1,
      "transactionDI": 1,
      "deviceUserDI": 2,
      "routeDI": 1,
      "DateTimeProceed": "\/Date(1406482920000+0100)\/",
      "Typetran": 1,
      "usedtokens": [
        {
          "usedtokenValue": 9.32,
          "usedtokenType": 3,
          "usedtokenId": "d798ee2d920e488487014d2a5ce46e7f"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "numberofTransactions": 1,
  "type": "insertit",
  "validation": "68W956!8$97123@Y$"
}
```

This storing the data in the same way that i am using for above but it stored into the database in the same format that i am sending

Now the difference between both in the database is:

[image]

Method i am using to Get the Request

```
[HttpPost]
public JObject UploadIT(dynamic objectData)
{
  //stuffs
}
```

Can anyone told me that why this inserting the same record in different ways?

Comment: Are you calling object.ToString() on your deserialized object?

Comment: I am deserializing using : MyModel transactionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(objectData.ToString());

Comment: ok, can you show the method that you create your dynamic object from the request?

Comment: i have edited my question please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using :

```
dynamic model = JObject.Parse(objectData.ToString());
```

I am taking objectData.ToString() and Parsing it to the dynamic object again and it's adding the spaces that i am not able to find into the Array.

That i can use Directly with `JObject.Parse(objectData.ToString())` also if i do not want to assign it to dynamic object again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your action code the behaviour is correct.
Since your `objectData` contains newline characters, and you insert just that to the db, the newline characters are preserved.

You can try `objectData.ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);`

**UPDATE:** You can do `objectData.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);`

Also you can use `Environment.Newline` instead of `\r\n` if you're certain request originates on Windows.

**UPDATE 2:** If you want to store pretty-print version, you'd have to re-serialize the transactionData: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transactionData, Formatting.Indented);` i'm not 100% sure if it will insert the spaces after ':', but you can always then `.Replace(":", ": ");`

Comment: thanks for the answer but if you can check the image carefully you will find that one of the object with name 'Tokens' having the behavior of in the first one "Tokens":1 and in second one "Tokens": 1 (you can see this difference in any object of that array)

Comment: @cracker, again the screenshot matches your posted fiddler request - check the request, you have spaces before values there.

Comment: what i am doing is i am sending the first array without spaces and it's inserting the same way but when i am formatting the json object that is adding the spaces into the request so what i need to do in this case as both are the array but the format is different

Comment: @cracker is your goal having these both with NO spaces in db? then use the code i provided.

Comment: i want to store array object that contains the spaces into the database.

Comment: i have posted the answer and it's working very well. @zaitsman thanks again. :)